# How to add classes to h2 block title tags in sidebar region

Tags: 7, theming

I need to add a class to the h2 block titles in a sidebar.  How can I do this in pre-process?  I haven't been able to find an example that shows how to isolate certain blocks.  I'm using Omega.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[template_preprocess_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7)

Inspect the block object in this preprocess function. You could use either the 'module' and 'delta' properties to target a specific block or the 'region' property to target all blocks in a certain region.

H2 css-classes are listed in the title_attributes_array. The code below shows how to add a new class. This example is based on a block generated by Views:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $block = $variables['block'];
  if ($block->module == 'views' && $block->delta == 'name_of_my_view-block') {
    $variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'my-new-class';
  }
}
```

Sidenote: dpm() by the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module is a handy tool for printing out the available data in variables:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did it! Question - is the $variables['block'] value a ref to the $variables['elements']['#block'] array?

Comment: Can I wrap the h2 tag in another div, or do I need to do that in a block template file?  I need to style the h2 titles with a ribbon using CSS.